# Django 1.10 - get site base url

Tags: python, django

How do you get base url of a site?

like - https://stackoverflow.com/

I would love to set it to settings.py

Thanks

**Answer:**

Really very sorry for such a poor question. :(

I was trying to link up a post by following code -

```
<a href="questions/{{ related_question.id }}">{{ related_question.question_text }}</a>
```

it took me from current page url but i expected from base url. I thought, i would get a solution like `site_url()` like Wordpress and could use it in `settings.py`.

But i don't have to do that. Starting `href` with `/....` starts from base url. So, above `<a>` tag should be -

```
<a href="/questions/{{ related_question.id }}">{{ related_question.question_text }}</a>
```

That's it.

Comment: Add more context. Where do you want to get it from? What do you want to do with it? Your question is very poor.

Comment: Hi, I edited my question

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to write your own template context processor which will return a SITE_URL from your settings file.

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors

Your function simply has to return a dict such as {"SITE_URL": settings.SITE_URL} and then all your templates will have "SITE_URL" in the context.

Another option would be to add a method to the question model e.g. get_url() which returns a site url with a slug and then use related_question.get_url inside your template.

And you should probably use a "url" tag in your templates, such as {% url 'question' related_question.id %} instead of hardcoding the URLs.